# how can I add my path to ~/.zshenv in order to install expo?

Tags: react-native, macos, android-studio, expo, zsh

I am installing Android studio and following this instruction. https://docs.expo.dev/workflow/android-studio-emulator/

I need to add

```
[ -d "$HOME/Library/Android/sdk" ] && ANDROID_SDK=$HOME/Library/Android/sdk || ANDROID_SDK=$HOME/Android/Sdk
echo "export ANDROID_SDK=$ANDROID_SDK" >> ~/`[[ $SHELL == *"zsh" ]] && echo '.zshenv' || echo '.bash_profile'
```

and

```
echo "export PATH=$HOME/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools:\$PATH" >> ~/`[[ $SHELL == *"zsh" ]] && echo '.zshenv' || echo '.bash_profile'`
```

to  ~/.zshrc

what I did is,
from the android studio, I see my path is Users/myname/Library/Android/sdk therefore,

```
nano ~/.zshrc
```

open ~/.zshrc window.
and added this two line like this...

```
[ -d "Users/<myname>/Library/Android/sdk" ] && ANDROID_SDK=Users/<myname>/Library/Android/sdk || ANDROID_SDK=Users/<myname>/Android/Sdk
echo "export ANDROID_SDK=$ANDROID_SDK" >> ~/`[[ $SHELL == *"zsh" ]] && echo '.zshenv' || echo '.bash_profile'
```

and next line, I added..

```
echo "export PATH=Users/<myname>/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools:\$PATH" >> ~/`[[ $SHELL == *"zsh" ]] && echo '.zshenv' || echo '.bash_profile'`
```

and it said, I need to make sure adb is working in terminal. So I typed adb in terminal, and it returns this err msg

```
zsh: command not found: adb
```

I am very new to shell things.. please help me!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to open the file with an editor: just run the two shell lines themselves in your terminal and they will append the EXPORT command to `.zshenv` with the proper ANDROID_SDK to be sourced next time you open the terminal and at the same time you'll the have ANDROID_SDK populated for your current session to keep on going with the setup.

The lines are doing the two following things:

- Checking if `$HOME/Library/Android/sdk` exists: if so assign `$HOME/Library/Android/sdk` to ANDROID_SDK, else assign it `$HOME/Android/Sdk`
- Checking if you're using zsh by running `$SHELL == *"zsh"`: if so, append `export ANDROID_SDK=$ANDROID_SDK` to `.zshenv`, if not, append it to `.bash_profile`

If you wanted to do that manually, open `.zshenv` and append to it `export ANDROID_SDK=$ANDROID_SDK` (without the echo part) where `$ANDROID_SDK` is the directory above mentioned ( `$HOME/Library/Android/sdk` or `$HOME/Android/Sdk` depending on you having the `$HOME/Library/Android/sdk` directory or not  )